# Vue 2.1 [Vue warn]: Property or method "_leaving" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js, transition

Since I've updated to the new Vue 2.1 version I get this message on console:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "_leaving" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.
> (found in component )

But if try again with Vue 2.0 this warning dissapears.

I do not understand, I'm using the default [transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components)

Comment: Can you put relevant code, or create a fiddle of it?

Comment: Have you updated other relevant dependencies as well if any?

Comment: Yes I've updated the vue template and others dependencies (npm told me what dependencies needed). Let me try to reproduce that in a fiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update again, problem has been fixed: see https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4300